# How can I connect my phone via Bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth

I didnt use bluetooth on my laptop before, I want to connect my laptop to my android phone.How can I do it?

I have kubuntu. I have blueman-applet app.Can you tell me how can I make this connection via use blueman-applet or any other app?

Output2:

```
ahmet@ahmet:~$ dmesg | grep -i blue
[    8.938600] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    8.938616] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    8.938619] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    8.938621] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    8.938627] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    8.974466] Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected event for opcode 0x0000
[  156.545210] audit: type=1107 audit(1591450806.154:109): pid=1209 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager" member="GetManagedObjects" mask="send" name="org.bluez" pid=2371 label="snap.electronplayer.electronplayer"
[  258.776493] Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected event for opcode 0x0000
[11265.323562] Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected event for opcode 0x0000
ahmet@ahmet:~$
```

Output:

```
hmet@ahmet:~$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 135 [8086:0893] (rev c4)
        Subsystem: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 135 BGN [8086:0262]
        Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
        Kernel modules: iwlwifi
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 8087:07da Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0bda:5728 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
ahmet@ahmet:~$
```

Comment: Enable discovery mode in your phone, then it should be seen in Kubuntu.

Comment: It is already enabled but I couldnt see any name about my laptop on my phone screen, there are only phone names.Also I dont know how can I see my phone's name on kubuntu.

Comment: Do you see any devices on Kubuntu?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6 I added the output.

Comment: Normally if you enable BT on Kubuntu, you should see devices that are close enough, then click one of those and pair. Can you see any devices there?

Comment: @Pilot6 I didnt use the blueman-applet app or any other app to connect bluetooth before so I dont know how can I see the devices.When I click the bluetooth icon, "set new device" buton is passive if you mean that button,

Comment: That means that something is wrong with BT. Are you sure it is there?

Comment: The phone is near the laptop.

Comment: Please add output of `dmesg | grep -i blue`

Comment: @Pilot6 I added it

Comment: As you can see there is a problem with the BT adapter. It doesn't work.